# iCloud and Push Notifications are enabled but the errors are still existing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have encountered the following error in Xcode 8

## errors in Xcode 8

Capabilities / iCloud

1. Add the iCloud feature to your App ID
2. Add iCloud Containers to your App ID

Capabilities / Push Notifications

1. Add the Push Notification feature to your App ID

then, I login apple developer account and verify the setting.

## verification result

1. Verified with iOS App ID
2. iCloud and Push Notifications are enabled in both development and distribution

It seems setting the correct, I restarted Xcode but the errors are still existing.

Please feel free to comment.

## Update

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error do you encounter?

Comment: under capabilities, encountered the error
1. Add the iCloud feature to your App ID
2. Add iCloud Containers to your App ID
3. Add the Push Notification feature to your App ID

Comment: Did you enabled "Remote Notifications" from "Background Modes" in Capabilities?

Comment: I don't know what it is. I found this link "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1". I try to figure out what it is. Thank you.

Comment: Enabled "Remote Notifications" from "Background Modes" in Capabilities. However, it is still showing error message.